# Package Control, "Install Package" Shows nothing when entered

Tags: windows-7, installation, sublimetext3, package-control

I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7 with Package Control installed, and I want to install a couple packages for syntax highlighting. I'm told I have to do this by hitting Ctrl+Shift+P and clicking 'Package Control: Install Package'. At that point something is supposed to appear where I can enter text, but as far as I can tell all it does is say, 'Loading Repositories [=====]' at the bottom for a half second and then stop. Besides the main editor window, there's nowhere else new to enter text or a link or something. Am I missing something from the process, or did I not understand one of the steps correctly?

Edit: It shows this error message in the console whenever I try to access the list of packages;

```
Exception in thread Thread-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./threading.py", line 901, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "package_control.commands.install_package_command in S:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 43, in run
  File "package_control.package_installer in S:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 54, in make_package_list
  File "package_control.package_manager in S:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 260, in list_available_packages
  File "package_control.downloaders.background_downloader in S:\Users\Nicholas\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Installed Packages\Package Control.sublime-package", line 52, in get_provider
KeyError: 'http://merlinthered.github.com/sublime-rainmeter/'
```

Comment: Activate the console, there is probably an error somewhere : View > Show console

Comment: It did give an error.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the error is simply saying that it can't download, access or parse a certain package. You may get more information about the specific error by posting it to [the Package Control GitHub issues page](https://github.com/wbond/sublime_package_control/issues) as the someone that knows the inner workings of the package control might be able to help you better.

You could try an reinstall of Sublime Text 3 and the Package Control. You may want to back-up your settings and packages, in case you want to go back to the current setup. You can find these using `Preferences > Browse Packages`.